# Dotted like tree structure

Tags: html, css, sass

I am having issue of cross browser issue on border dotted style. I have create one or multiple dot via using `border` `style` `dotted`
But its working on chrome perfectly. But in firefox it will not work. So what is the better idea to make it happen on all browser?

I can't change markup i can make only from css

[**Here is fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/b4vez5qx/)

And desired result. [image]

```css
.span:before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: 10px;
    left: 0;
    width: 0;
    height: 4px;
    border-top: 4px dotted #333;
    overflow: hidden;
}
.span {
    position: relative;
}

.level-1 {
    padding-left: 12px;
    
    &:before {
        width: 6px;
    }
}

.level-2 {
    padding-left: 18px;
    
    &:before {
        width: 12px;
    }
}

.level-3 {
    padding-left: 24px;
    
    &:before {
        width: 18px;
    }
}

.level-4 {
    padding-left: 30px;
    
    &:before {
        width: 24px;
    }
}
```

```html
<div class="span level-1">Test</div>
<div class="span level-2">Test 2</div>
<div class="span level-3">Test 3</div>
<div class="span level-4">Test 4</div>
```

Comment: I use chrome also not same as your desired result, it's don't have any dotted

Comment: Check fiddle link.. Its only working on chrome

Comment: `border-top: 3.95px dotted #333;` would solve the problem. Yeah, don't ask… The way browsers are adapting to available width by getting dots closer (replace 12px by 14/16/18px to see it in effect), I'd use an **SVG** as background with `repeat-x`: you precisely know its width and spacing (depends on the viewBox) so you can have a cross-browser solution :)

Comment: Then can you tell me how to make via svg bg?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may try `radial-gradient` as a repeated background:

```css
.span {
  position: relative;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff),
    radial-gradient(circle at center,#000 30%,transparent 40%);
  background-size:100% 100%,6px 12px;
  background-position:0 3px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat,repeat;
}
.level-1 {
  padding-left: 12px;
  background-position:6px 0,0 3px;
}

.level-2 {
  padding-left: 18px;
  background-position:12px 0,0 3px;
}

.level-3 {
  padding-left: 24px;
  background-position:18px 0,0 3px;
}

.level-4 {
  padding-left: 30px;
  background-position:24px 0,0 3px;
}
```

```html
<div class="span level-1">Test</div>
<div class="span level-2">Test 2</div>
<div class="span level-3">Test 3</div>
<div class="span level-4">Test 4</div>
```

Or use SVG as background:

```css
.span {
  position: relative;
  background-image:
    linear-gradient(#fff,#fff),
    url('data:image/svg+xml,<svg  xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" height="100" width="100"><circle cx="50" cy="50" r="35" fill="#000" /></svg>');
  background-size:100% 100%,7px 7px;
  background-position:0 10px;
  background-repeat:no-repeat,repeat-x;
}
.level-1 {
  padding-left: 12px;
  background-position:6px 0,0 6px;
}

.level-2 {
  padding-left: 18px;
  background-position:14px 0,0 6px;
}

.level-3 {
  padding-left: 24px;
  background-position:20px 0,0 6px;
}

.level-4 {
  padding-left: 30px;
  background-position:28px 0,0 6px;
}
```

```html
<div class="span level-1">Test</div>
<div class="span level-2">Test 2</div>
<div class="span level-3">Test 3</div>
<div class="span level-4">Test 4</div>
```